# How to use multiple databases in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a requirement that I need to create the more than one database to my application,when user login based on there ID need to pick the username and password from the corresponding database and Login.(With out using more than one sessoinfactory).only by creating hibernate cfg.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory1 = new  Configuration().configure("oracleconfig.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory2 = new Configuration().configure("derbyconfig.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

here its herd coded the cfg file how i can give dynamically.

Comment: http://www.javabeat.net/configuring-multiple-databases-in-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

For generating and changing a hibernate connection you may like this link: [Hibernate Documentation - Chapter 3: Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)